# What's the general term for pests and everything that can harm your crops?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

When you grow *some* cultures in your farm you need to use *some* products against *some* "unfriendly" things that might harm your crops.

- Fungicides are used to kill **fungi or fungal spores**.
- Insecticides are used to kill **insects**.
- Herbicides are are meant to control **weeds**.

What word could be used for generalization of the words that I have bolded?

Comment: *Herbicides* are used to control ***weeds***.

Comment: @PeterShor Sorry?

Comment: *Pesticide* is a general term used to cover chemicals that kill harmful things, including *fungus, insects*, ***and*** *weeds*. So dividing these chemicals into *fungicides, insecticides, pesticides* is really misleading.

Comment: I'd say "pests" is likely what you want, and it's not limited to noxious plants. Fungicides kill fungi, Insecticides kill insects, herbicides kill plants (herbaceous things). All three fall under the general category of "pesticides", which kill, well, pests.

Comment: Based upon the question as you've written it, it sounds like you're asking what the common terms is for "fungi or fungal spores, insects, and weeds", not for the chemicals that kill them.  If you intend to ask about the communal chemical (as the accepted answer suggests), seems you should change your bolding to reflect that?

Comment: *Pests* strongly implies insects and rodents, not weeds, despite how the word *pesticide* seems to be used in some parts of the world (here, on the Canadian prairies, *pesticides* seem to be for insects and creates and *herbicides* for weeds).

Comment: *What's the general term for lifeforms that can harm crops?* **pests**

Comment: A couple questions to narrow down possible answers: 1) What geographic regions will this usage be used in? E.g., UK, USA, etc. 2) Would you prefer it to be something that should be technical and formal, or informal and generalized? 3) Do you know what sentence(s) you want to use it in, and if so, can you provide it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think your definition for the term *pesticide* is perhaps too narrow.

Per *Saunders Comprehensive Veterinary Dictionary*, 2nd Ed., ***pesticide*** is defined as (p. 865):

> a poison used to destroy pests of any sort

And it defines ***pest*** (p. 865) as

> an organism that injures, irritates, or damages livestock or crops

Therefore, I think your answer for the general word is ***pesticide***.

See also this comprehensive definition in Wikipedia for [***pesticide***.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesticide)

> Pesticides are substances that are meant to control pests or weeds.[1] The term pesticide includes all of the following: herbicide, insecticide, insect growth regulator, nematicide, termiticide, molluscicide, piscicide, avicide, rodenticide, predacide, bactericide, insect repellent, animal repellent, antimicrobial, fungicide, disinfectant (antimicrobial), and sanitizer.[2] The most common of these are herbicides which account for approximately 80% of all pesticide use.[3] Most pesticides are intended to serve as plant protection products (also known as crop protection products), which in general, protect plants from weeds, fungi, or insects.

There is also the word ***biocide***, which is not as much in general use. It is defined by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/biocide) as:

> a substance (such as an algicide or fungicide) that destroys or inhibits the growth or activity of living organisms

It is a term used by environmental groups, [such as in this post](http://www.cagreens.org/platform/biocides) by the Green Party of California.

Comment: Adding anecdotal support for this answer: I do research into resistance to crop fungicides and it's common in the field to use pesticides as an umbrella term for chemicals that target pests and pathogens

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but your answer doesn't make it quite clear enough to suit me. "Biocide" is a much *broader* term than "pesticide". A biocide can kill *any* living thing, not just pests and things that cause damage.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I think a clarification is warranted, @Hank.

Comment: I totally missed the biocide suggestion in the answer. I thought you were suggesting it. I would also have to say the answer should be suggesting "pest", not "pesticide". The OP asked for the term that describes the things hurting your crops, not the term for things that hurt the things hurting your crops. It can be fixed with a simple rewording, though.

Comment: I answered before a couple of edits were made to the question. You're right *pest* is the word that the OP wants. I just didn't have time to edit my answer to fit the edited question. (You can look at the questioner's edits.) I would not use the term biocide at all.

Comment: IMO, _pest_ is too flippant a word in the USA for the OP's usage. It's not technically wrong, but when talking about these things among people in the US, it's rarely ever used. When I hear pest, it's almost always _pest-control_ or calling _someone_ a pest. I can't speak for anyone in any industries, just common spoken usage. _Plague_ and _blight_ are the two words most commonly spoken for the concepts those words carry by association, in my experience in the USA. Maybe in the UK, pest is used less flippantly. In the US, it's usually referring to something that's being _annoying_.

Comment: If it's for something industry-based, or outside the USA, I have no personal insight. However, the OP specifically says _general term_ in the question. _Often_ that would _imply_ the non-technical usage as the preference, and therefore industry terms would be less appropriate than what the general public uses. I've lived all over the US on both coasts and the bits in the middle, and I'm trying to explain that _pest_ is just not used this way by most people, in _general_. If this question didn't ask for a general term, I would completely agree with your assessment, sans the snide valley remark.

Answer (score 12):

You could possibly call those bolded works **blights**:

> #### Blight
>
> *noun, BrE*
>
> - a person or thing that mars or prevents growth, improvement, or prosperity.

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/blight))

Comment: Not a good suggestion. "Blight" is a term used for a specific class of plant disease - typically those caused by fungi such as mildews, rusts, and smuts

Comment: @Tullochgorum That is one use of it, yes.

Comment: Hank - it's the dominant usage, by far. To use "blight" to refer to any other form of plant disease would almost certainly cause misunderstanding.

Comment: @Tullochgorum Dominant where? Do you have evidence supporting your universal claim that it is dominant everywhere? Despite it being a BrE usage, I've heard it used very often in the southern US, where farming is very prevalent. While I am aware of the other usage, I have seen nothing that makes it the only usage.

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of a single word that neatly and unambiguously fits your description. The best words that I can think of are more generic than your specific usage, and refer to the organisms being unwanted, an annoyance and likely to cause harm. If you use these, you would probably have to define what you meant first. You could use words such as:

- [**Menace**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/menace)
- [**Nuisance**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nuisance)
- [**Affliction**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affliction)

I would put the word **blight** under this type of word, but add a note of caution to its use. There are several plant diseases (fungal infections, I think) that are called *[blight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blight)* (e.g. potato blight), so this may be what people take it to mean.

You could also use words that imply a large number of organisms causing damage, such as:

- [**Infestation**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/infestation)
- [**Plague**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plague)

But, probably the best word to use would just be [**pests**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pest) as this doesn't *have* to be limited to animal pests.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the word ***[parasite](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parasites)***.

> an organism living in, with, or on another organism in *parasitism*

- [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parasites)

**[Parasitism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parasitism)**:

> an intimate association between organisms of two or more kinds; especially :  one in which a parasite obtains **benefits from a host which it usually injures**

- [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parasitism)

Since all of the organisms you mention benefit from feeding off the crops (or, in the case of weeds, competing for sunlight and water) to the detriment of the crops, you could say that the fungi, insects, and weeds are all **parasites**.

Comment: Parasitism implies taking resources directly from a living thing.  Merely consuming a resource also needed by something is not parasitism.  (Were this the case, someone in front of you grabbing the last turkey out of the freezer at your grocery store at Thanksgiving might be called a parasite.)

Answer (score 3):

The Illinois farmers and agronomists my shop has interviewed tend to use the term ***pressure*** as a generic for all the factors which threaten yield: 'weed pressure', 'disease pressure', 'drought pressure', 'wildlife pressure', and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

*[Plague and Pestilence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plague%20and%20pestilence&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1000&year_end=2100&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cplague%20and%20pestilence%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bplague%20and%20pestilence%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPlague%20and%20Pestilence%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPlague%20and%20pestilence%3B%2Cc0)* is a common phrase to describe forces that usually ravage a farm if not a countryside, or even a whole country. It couples nicely with *famine and war* as well as *loot and plunder*.

Things that prevent growth and usually kill what is already there in a generalized sense would be a *[blight](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blight&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cblight%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bblight%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBlight%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBLIGHT%3B%2Cc0)*. While it may be defined for the prevention of growth, it almost always implies that it also *kills* or destroys what is already there. There are some popular phrases that use *blight*, like *[encroaching blight](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blight&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cblight%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bblight%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBlight%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBLIGHT%3B%2Cc0)*.

I would choose one of these two, depending on the context, *preferring* **blight**.